# Transformation rule under translation of the Fourier transform of a scalar field

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation, classical-field-theory

Let $\phi(x)$ be a real classical scalar field which satisfies the Klein-Gordon equation; without loss of generality it can be written as:

$$ \phi(x) = \int  \frac{d\vec k}{(2\pi)^{3/2} 2 \omega_k} \left \{   \tilde \phi (k) e^{-ikx} + \tilde \phi ^*(k) e^{ikx} \right \}_{\big|_{k^0=\omega(\vec k)}}$$

Since $\phi(x)$ is a scalar field I require that under Lorentz transformation

$$
x \rightarrow x'(x)=\Lambda x \; \Rightarrow \; \phi (x) \rightarrow \phi'(x'(x)) \overset{!}{=}\phi (x)$$

and applying that condition to the integral representation of $\phi (x)$ I deduce that even $\tilde \phi (k)$ has to be a scalar field: if

$$\begin{cases}
x \rightarrow x'(x)=\Lambda x \\
k \rightarrow k'(k)=\Lambda k 
\end{cases}$$

the measure $\frac{d\vec k}{(2\pi)^{3/2} 2 \omega_k}$ and the exponential $e^{-ikx}$ are invariant and hence

$$ \phi'(x'(x)) = \phi (x) \Leftrightarrow \tilde \phi '(k'(k)) = \tilde \phi(k) \\$$

QUESTION: But when it comes to translation invariance how do things work?

Since $\phi(x)$ is a scalar field I require, as before, that:

$$ x \rightarrow x'(x)=x+a \; \Rightarrow \; \phi (x) \rightarrow \phi'(x'(x)) \overset{!}{=}\phi (x) $$

but in this case I find a strange transformation rule for $\tilde \phi(k)$: if

$$\begin{cases}
x \rightarrow x'(x)= x + a \\
k \rightarrow k'(k)= k 
\end{cases}$$

the measure $\frac{d\vec k}{(2\pi)^{3/2} 2 \omega_k}$ is invariant but the exponential is not: $e^{-ikx} \rightarrow e^{-ik'x'}=e^{-ikx-ika} $ and hence I find:

$$ \phi'(x'(x)) = \phi (x) \Leftrightarrow \tilde \phi '(k'(k)) = \tilde \phi(k) e^{ika}\\$$

Is this transformation rule correct? what kind of field is $\tilde \phi(k)$ then?

Comment: Note that the Fourier transform of $f(x+a)$ is $\mathrm e^{ika}\tilde f(k)$ (cf. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties)).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform do you think the transformation rule for $\tilde \phi(k)$ is correct then? do fields with that behavior (invariant under Lorents transformation but not under translation) have a particular name? Like, for example, pseudo-scalar are fields invariant under Lorentz transformation but not under parity